# How to align multiple StatusBarItems to the right side in XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, alignment

I have a `StatusBar` with 4 items in it on my C# application. I basically want to float the last two `StatusBarItems` to the right. I've tried it by setting them both with `HorizontalAlignment="Right"`, but that did only work for the last item.

```
<StatusBar Name="statusBar1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
    <StatusBarItem />
    <StatusBarItem />
    <StatusBarItem HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
    <StatusBarItem HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
</StatusBar>
```

I started googling and I came up with the following URL:

[Blogspot](http://kentb.blogspot.ch/2007/10/perfect-wpf-statusbar.html)

Is this really the only solution for this, or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that the default `ItemsPanel` for the `StatusBar` is the `DockPanel`.  The `DockPanel` will, by default, try to fill the remaining space with the last item.  So the last `StatusBarItem` you add to the `StatusBar` will fill the remainder of the space.  To take advantage of this, you can simply nest `StatusBarItems` like this:

```
<StatusBar Name="statusBar1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
  <StatusBarItem Content="Item 1"/>
  <StatusBarItem Content="Item 2" />
  <StatusBarItem HorizontalAlignment="Right">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <StatusBarItem  Content="Item 3"/>
      <StatusBarItem Content="Item 4"/>
      <ProgressBar Height="15" Width="50" IsIndeterminate="True" Margin="5,0"/>
    </StackPanel>
  </StatusBarItem>
</StatusBar>
```

Note that the `HorizontalAlignment` of the 3rd `StatusBarItem` is set to `Right` so that it's content will be right-aligned.

Of course, you don't have to have Item 3 and Item 4 be `StatusBarItems`, they could be other controls, such as `Buttons` or `ProgressBar` as I've demonstrated above as well.  The `StatusBarItem` is simply a container that wraps items in a `StatusBar`, similar to how a `ComboBoxItem` wraps items inside of a `ComboBox`.

The `StatusBar` will wrap it's contents in `StatusBarItems` automatically, if you don't use them, so items 1 and 2 could just as easily be `TextBoxes`.  The primary reason to use `StatusBarItems` is in the case where you want to control how the `StatusBarItem` works, like in the 3rd `StatusBarItem` where it sets the `HorizontalAlignment` manually, rather than rely on the default.

Comment: Tried that too.. that unfortunately just leads to the following result: http://www.abload.de/img/02032013291y0h.png

Comment: Ah, sorry, I'm on a mac at the moment, so can't test this out.  Is there a `HorizontalContentAlignment` on the `StatusBar` that you can set to `Stretch`?  I will get back to my PC soon and test it out.

Comment: np. and yeah, there is is, however that did not the trick either.

Comment: Ok, now that I had a moment to test it out on my PC, I've updated the answer to accomplish what I believe you're looking for.  Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: cool! didn't know, i could even use `StatusBarItems` as containers. thank you sir, exactly what i was looking for! ;)

Comment: any idea though how to properly display the content of your `StackPanel`? i came up with fiddling around the margin values, but i guess there is a more proper way to do so?

Comment: What kind of display are you looking for?  I generally think using `Margins` is a good approach since it is relative and responsive.  But I'm not clear on how you want them to look.  A `StackPanel` will squish everything as close as possible (considering margins, etc), so if you don't want that, you could replace the `StackPanel` with a `Grid` and use columns for more control.  The width of the columns can be dynamic, or based on the content or fixed.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: yeah. it's just that i'm pretty new to WPF, so i am still looking for best practises (maybe you can recommend a good source?). but ok i guess i will go for margins then :-)

Comment: Layout in WPF takes a little getting used to, but once you're comfortable with it, it will make your life much easier.  [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743070/whats-a-good-guide-to-wpf-panels-layout-in-general) has some answers pointing to resources, and a simple Google Search for WPF Layout Tutorial or the like will probably produce some good results as well.  Good luck!

Comment: @BrianS Great tip but it doesn't work when there are separators between each items :(

Comment: Yeah, it seems to kill separators. :(

Answer (score 28):

As mentioned, the default container is `DockPanel`.  As such, you can set as many items as needed to `DockPanel.Dock="Right"`.  Just be sure that the `fill` item is last.

```
<StatusBar>
    <StatusBarItem DockPanel.Dock="Right">
        <Slider Width="100" />
    </StatusBarItem>
    <StatusBarItem DockPanel.Dock="Right">
        <Label>Zoom: 100 %</Label>
    </StatusBarItem>
    <StatusBarItem>
        <TextBlock>Ready</TextBlock>
    </StatusBarItem>
</StatusBar>
```

Comment: Your solution looks cleaner than the accepted answer

Comment: Protip: When you dock more than one `StatusBarItem` like this, they will be in reverse order (because the last one added shoves the rest of the left). To avoid this with the least effort, set one right-docked `StatusBarItem`'s content to a `StackPanel` with horizontal orientation.

Answer (score 3):

You can also set `LastChildFill` to `false` and then use `DockPanel.Dock=Right` just like the solution above, without having to worry about the last item consuming all the space:

```
<StatusBar>
  <StatusBar.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <DockPanel LastChildFill="False" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </StatusBar.ItemsPanel>
</StatusBar>
```

Answer (score 3):

Another interesting way of achieving this is to replace default panel of `StatusBar` with `Grid`, which will give you far more control over the layout of items.

```
<StatusBar Height="30">
  <StatusBar.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      </Grid>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </StatusBar.ItemsPanel>

  <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="0">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProgressMessage, Mode=OneWay}" />
  </StatusBarItem>

  <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="1">
    <ProgressBar Value="{Binding ProgressValue, Mode=OneWay}" Width="100" Height="10" />
  </StatusBarItem>

  <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="2">
    <Ellipse Width="12" Height="12" Stroke="Gray" Fill="Red" />
  </StatusBarItem>
</StatusBar>
```