# WPF XAML status bar items align to right

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have these items inside a status bar and I can't align the progress bar to the right. All items are inside a grid. Please Help.

```xml
<Grid>
    <StatusBar HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="30"
        x:Name="StatusBarBase">
        <TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource loading}" x:Name="progressBarTextBlock"/>
        <Separator/>
        <ProgressBar Width="100" Height="20" x:Name="progressBar"/>
    </StatusBar>
</Grid>
```

[image: Required result.]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177079/how-to-align-multiple-statusbaritems-to-the-right-side-in-xaml

Comment: Thank you @Andy but it did not work inside the grid.

Comment: @Toni It will work if you tried to wrap the `<ProgressBar />` with `<StatusBarItem HorizontalAlignment="Right" >`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to align multiple StatusBarItems to the right side in XAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177079/how-to-align-multiple-statusbaritems-to-the-right-side-in-xaml)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`StatusBar` is an `ItemsControl`. Items in a `StatusBar` are defined as `StatusBarItem` objects.

Place your items in `StatusBarItem` and set the horizontal alignment for `StatusBarItem` with `ProgressBar`.

```
<!-- Edited indentation to make code more readable. -->

<StatusBar HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="30" x:Name="StatusBarBase">
    <StatusBarItem>
        <TextBlock Text="Text" x:Name="progressBarTextBlock"/>
    </StatusBarItem>            
    <Separator />
    <StatusBarItem HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <ProgressBar Width="100" Height="20" x:Name="progressBar"/>
    </StatusBarItem>            
</StatusBar>
```

Comment: I tried putting every item inside a `StatusBarItem` and it did not work before because I added the `Separator` too. I followed your suggestion and It worked. Thank you so much @user2250152.